# Is there an archive of comments from the Facebook Live Stream social plugin?

Tags: stream, widget, live, facebook-social-plugins

I'm wondering if it is possible for an app administrator to get the archive of comments from a [Live Stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream).

We'd like to be able to look over the comments to prepare a report for our clients.

I've done some searching and this doesn't appear to exist, but wasn't sure if there was an update that may provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the comments plugin's comments can be retrieved via the API, but not those of the Live Stream plugin